# List categories of a post hierarchically?

Tags: theme-development, categories, themes, loop

Let's say I got the following categories:

```
Style
  |
  + Shoes
  + Pants
```

If I make a post and put it in the Style and Shoes category, it will list them alphabetically instead of hierarchically. So it would list it as Shoes, Style instead of Styles, Shoes.

How can I do this? I tried using "the_category('> ', 'multiple')" but that outputs "Style, Shoes, Style"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fetch the post categories, then pass them into `wp_list_categories`  to take care of displaying them hierarchally.

Something like..

```
wp_list_categories( array( 
    'include' => array_keys( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category' ) ), 
    'title_li' => '' 
) );
```

Hope that helps.. :)